# Is there a way to make VS Code create HTML file by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create .HTML file whenever I choose New File, is this possible?

Comment: Added since question: `files.defaultLanguage` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no way to configure VS Code to do this out of the box so I wrote an extension to do it. You can download that extension from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-newfile-languagemode).

It adds two types of commands:

- `editor.newFile.withCurrentLanguageMode` will open a new file with the same language mode as the currently active file
- `editor.newFile.withLanguageMode.<languageId>` will open a new file with specified id as the language mode. The language must be first added to the configuration and a keybinding set up

So to set up one command to open new html files and another to open markdown files, you can add settings like this:

settings.json:

```
"editor.newFile.languageModes": ["markdown", "html"]
```

keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t 0",
    "command": "editor.newFile.withCurrentLanguageMode",
    "when": ""
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t 1",
    "command": "editor.newFile.withLanguageMode.markdown",
    "when": ""
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t 2",
    "command": "editor.newFile.withLanguageMode.html",
    "when": ""
}
```

Using these settings you would then press "ctrl+shift+t" then "0" to open a new file with the same language as whatever file you have active, "ctrl+shift+t" then "1" to open a new file with "markdown" as the language mode, and "ctrl+shift+t" then "2" to open a new file with "html" as the language mode. Of course, you can customize the keybindings however you want and set the languages to whatever you want.

Answer (score 32):

In VS Code, my separate folders for different HTML projects are stored under an **UNTITLED (WORKSPACE)**.

For a new HTML file, I simply ***right-click*** on any folder in (WORKSPACE), select ***New File*** and then *name that file with an HTML extension*. The file is completely empty with no HTML whatsoever. Then, because the Emmet plugin is built into VS Code, I simply type an ***!*** (exclamation point) and press ***TAB*** or ***ENTER*** and the empty file is filed with a complete HTML5 boilerplate.

5 simple steps to create an HTML file in Visual Studio Code

1. **right-click** on folder in (WORKSPACE)
2. Select **New File**
3. Name the file with an HTML extension
4. Type **!** (one exclamation point only)
5. Press **TAB** or **ENTER**